# MySQL why AUTO_INCREMENT does not start at 0 when using CREATE TABLE in MySQL Workbench (8.0)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, auto-increment, create-table

Using MySQL Workbench 8.0, I'm using table table create statements based on an existing (database) table `containers`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `containers`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `containers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `waste_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,

[.. etc etc ..]

  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `removed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4293 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
```

Why is this statement generating an `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4293` that starts at value `4293`?
Since it is a table CREATE statement, is it always expecting that one copies existing records in the old table to the newly created tables? And continues working with the newly created table? 
I would expect it to start at the value `0` when creating an new table.

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Just remove the _AUTO_INCREMENT=4293_ and it will start at 0.

Comment: @nacho I think OP knows that...the specific question, if I've understood correctly, is why mysql workbench auto-generated the statement to include the `= 4293`.

Comment: I think the idea is that the function is mainly used in exporting data.

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your question but I would expect to start from 1 why do you expect 0? Also I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: The existing table has id with the value 4238 so when you generate a table through workbench it will start with 4239, otherwise you could never transfer your data to the new table because the id's from 1 - 4238 are already used.

Comment: @Grumpy how so first thing op does is drop the table

Comment: @P.Salmon That is also generated by the workbench. This is part of a data recovery script. The idea is that the table is exactly as it was before,